# How to find distance from AR camera to a marker in real world using Unity3d

Tags: android, camera, unity-game-engine, distance, unityscript

I'm new to scripting and I'm trying really hard to make an AR application for Android mobiles in Unity3d. I came up to a problem, that cannot solve no matter what I've though off.

Here is the situation. I have an AR camera scripted with the NyARToolkit plugin for Augmented Reality for Unity3d.

This AR camera, tagged as "MainCamera", needs to get switched off, when a certain distance is reached (meaning moving away the android phone) form the marker that renders the model on it.
When this distance is reached, I want to set off "MainCamera" and load another unity scene.

The following code is what I've tried so far, without much success. Need to mention that, this script is attached on "MainCamera", and this is the gameObject that needs to be disabled.

Here is the script:

```
#pragma strict
 var mainCamera : Transform;
 var camera : GameObject;
 function Update() {
 var distance = Vector3.Distance(mainCamera.position, transform.position);
 if(distance<0) {
     Debug.Log("CloseUp camera is on : " + distance);
 }
  if(distance > 1) {
    Debug.Log("CloseUp camera is off : " + distance);
     Camera.main.gameObject.SetActiveRecursively(false);
   }
}
```

Can somebody, take a look at my code snippet and post a working edit, so I can get the distance right and set the camera off when user moves the android mobile away form the marker?

Thank you all in advance for your answers.

"Edit 1"

I know I'm not even close to the function need to make work on mobile, but this [link](https://itunes.apple.com/hk/app/rangefinder/id369171302?mt=8), will give you a view of that functionality. I need to get the distance from the marker to mobile first, and if that distance is e.g. above 1.5 m, the AR camera should be switched off and a new level should be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what exactly wasn't working. Based on what I could piece together from your post and the code sample you provided you just need to add the level loading code.

```
#pragma strict
var mainCamera : Transform;
var camera : GameObject;
function Update() {
var distance = Vector3.Distance(mainCamera.position, transform.position);
if(distance<0) {
   Debug.Log("CloseUp camera is on : " + distance);
}
if(distance > 1) {
  Debug.Log("CloseUp camera is off : " + distance);
  // If you are loading a new scene you likely don't need to bother turning off the camera
  Camera.main.gameObject.SetActiveRecursively(false);
  Application.LoadLevel ("nameOfTheLevelToLoad");
}
}
```

Comment: Hi @Luke Noonan. The problem is that when the camera moves in scene above distance 1, it should switched off, but it keeps switching on/off in intervals. Furthermore, although this code, seems to work in Unity3d play window, upon testing in android mobile, when user moves away from marker, nothing happens. I believe, there must be something added to the Update function to properly function, but I'm novice to know about it. Furthermore for this concept, take a look at my "edit". Any clues on that?

Comment: Ahhh I assumed you had the other stuff working.

The app you linked to likely uses some tricky geometry and image analysis stuff to get the distance. 

I can't speak to the NyARToolkit (I have only use Vuforia myself) but I don't believe the in application world units necessarily correlate with real world units. (ie. 1 game unit = 1 Meter) I would start by having the app show the `distance` on screen to figure out what your distance is in units. Then I would work on the scene transition once you know that the distances are correct. 
sorry its not a more direct answer.

Comment: Well @Luke Noonan, since you haven't used NyARToolkit but you have some experience with Vuforia, do you happen to know how this can be done in Unity3d? Can you post a sample code of how to get distance on screen units?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I use...

```
float DistanceMainCamPosSpawnedPrefab = 
Vector3.Distance(MainCam.transform.position, 
m_SpawnedOnePrefab.transform.position); // the m_SpawnedOnePrefab would be your marker


if (DistanceMainCamPosSpawnedPrefab > .3f && DistanceMainCamPosSpawnedPrefab <  
.5f)
   {
      // run your code here
    }
```